# Danish letter ø is shown as � in related products

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm having a really weird problem with the letter 'ø' in my related products view. For some products, not all just some, this letter is shown as � instead. I have found the entries in the database where everything seems fine, the related.phtml file is UTF-8 the string is echoed like this:

```
echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName());
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Echoing the names without htmlEscape doesn't make any difference either.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a problem with your DB encoding, make sure your tables (especially the product eav tables) are using a utf-8 encoding, such as `utf8_general_ci` and check what the actual name looks like in DB.

The main table should be `catalog_product_entity_varchar`

Comment: Thanks! I have actually checked that already. The catalog_product_entity_varchar is indeed utf8_general_ci and everything looks right in that one.

Comment: then check `catalog/product/list/related.phtml` and make sure the file is encoded using UTF-8

Comment: I have chosen UTF-8 as charset when saving in TextWrangler. However, upon inspecting through terminal, it tells me 'charset=us-ascii'. Seems to be the culprit. What is the easiest way to convert it on os x?

Comment: Or maybe not.. I have found some articles claiming that UTF-8 and US-ASCII is actually the same. Could the error be something else instead?

Comment: Those will be strings without special characters. The 128 ASCII characters have the same representation in UTF-8

Comment: @fschmengler - i'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that the charset is the error, or that it is not the error?

Comment: What I'm saying is that US-ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so  "UTF-8 and US-ASCII is actually the same." is wrong, but inspecting a string that does not contain non-ascii characters will not recognize it as UTF-8 although it is valid UTF-8

Comment: In short, it might appear as being identical, but won't get interpreted as if it were. Get Notepad++ and convert it to UTF-8 Without BOM. That should do the trick.